# Why can't I use Java 8 in Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

As far as I can understand Java 8 support should work out of the box in the the newest Eclipse Luna release, however nothing I do seems to make JavaSE-1.8 appear under Execution Environments. I have installed jdk-8u25-windows-x64. The JDK has been detected and is in use by Eclipse:
[image: jdk1.8.0_25 selected]
But no JavaSE-1.8 under Execution Environments:
[image: Execution Environments page without JavaSE-1.8]
The exact Eclipse version:
[image: Eclipse about box]

I have tried using both the JRE and the JDK, and
I have even tried installing the Java 8 for Kepler SR2 plugin, but to no avail.

Details from the installed JDK: [image: JDK details]

I should mention that javac compiles classes using java 8 features just fine, and java runs them without problems.

Comment: Whats the exact location for the JRE?

Comment: Uhm I have the JRE installed in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25 and the JDK (which contains the JRE as well) in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25.

Comment: Have you tried switching to the JRE as standard from the JDK?

Comment: Tried both (I updated the post after switching from the JRE to the JDK, didn't make any difference)

Comment: If the Execution Environment doesn’t show up, it doesn’t help playing around with settings or the jre/jdk. It’s obviously an installation issue. Please enter the “Installation Details” and check the version number of the “Eclipse IDE for Java developers” module which should show up in the list of installed software.

Comment: Found [another hint](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments#Installing_Execution_Environment_Descriptions)

Comment: Prove that this JDK/JRE8 is actually version 8. Run it via java -version to be sure, because I think Eclipse actually does something similar to build the Exec environments.

Comment: @jdv: don’t question the OP’s ability to provide the correct information. Whether Eclipse shows the Execution Environment for `JavaSE-1.8` does not depend on any locally installed JRE at all. Either it supports it, then it will be in the list, otherwise it doesn’t.

Comment: @Holger did you read what I said, or just decided that my use of the imperative meant something else? When solving problems you work from the known to the unknown, and when confronted with an odd mystery I would want to start from the beginning. Is the location just *named* JDK8 or is it *actually* JDK8. And this version of Eclipse supports JDK8, but only if there is actually a v. 8 VM (or compatible VM) to be found.

Comment: @jdv: again, that is completely irrelevant. If the particular Eclipse version supports Java 8, it will list `JavaSE-1.8` in its Execution Environments even if there is no local Java 1.8 installed. It will then tell you if it didn’t find a compatible JRE if you select it, but since it isn’t even in the list and can’t be selected, that’s nothing to bother.

Comment: That's fine, and this is why I didn't provide an *answer*. I didn't know how that was populated, and I suspect you didn't either until you looked. The point is that we have a mystery about why a version of Eclipse that is for Java 8 doesn't have the entry. To solve mysteries you ask questions and prove them.

Comment: http://imgur.com/6QoPVYK:

`C:\Users\poizan>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java" -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)`

Comment: @Holder I don't know what you mean by "Installation Details". I downloaded the 64-bit zip from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/lunasr1 and unpacked it, so obviously it won't show up in the list of installed software.

Comment: Just realised that you meant Help->Installation Details. Clicking the update button there made Eclipse update several different things, which apparently fixed the problem.

Comment: @poizan42: right, I didn’t explain it further as in your third screenshot there is a button at the bottom labeled “Installation Details”. Anyway, I’m glad that it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently going into Help->Installation Details and clicking Update (which isn't the same as Help->Check for Updates) fixed the problem. No idea how it ended up in that state to begin with though...

Comment: On a fresh PC, with no Java previously installed : 
1. downloading latest eclipse-java-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64.zip 
2. downloading 8u25-b18/jre-8u25-windows-x64.exe, and installing
worked out of the box

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using JRE 1.8.  You probably need JDK 1.8 which is the development environment  (Java SE Development Kit). It includes a complete JRE plus tools for developing, debugging, and monitoring Java applications.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: @Dawnkeeper then I don't know then.

Comment: Didn't make any difference